# Return 3221225725 in a code for simple probability operation

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a code that do a simple operation of probability, but it always return the same value(3221225725). I rewrote and changed the code several times (changed variables types, stopped using switch, created a variable for x-y, etc) but it keeps returning the same value. Do someone knows why it keeps doing this?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

float z;
float y;
float a = z - y;

int factorial(float x)
{
    if (x == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return x * factorial(x - 1);
    }
}

int main()
{

    cout << "Insert total number of elements or press 0 to exit" << endl;
    cin >> z;
    cout << "Insert total number of attempts or press 0 to exit" << endl;
    cin >> y;

    if (z > 0 && y > 0)
    {
        return (factorial(z) / (factorial(y)) * (factorial(a)));
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186584/discussion-on-question-by-thalles-machado-return-3221225725-in-a-code-for-simple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay there are several small issues with your code, but together they make a whole heap of problems.

Here is a "working" version that solves most of your problems, comments in the code indicate what mistakes you made: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0716e3a1fc7ecafc

Big issues you made:

- You initialized "a" with values from "z" and "y" before they were initialized, this means "a" contained uninitialized memory, and you will get random results.
- You are doing a direct comparison with a floating point number using "==" floating point numbers are not perfect representations, and the introduce small amounts of error with each math operation. When comparing floating point numbers you almost always need to compare them with some reasonable tolerance like within .00001.
- You were using the "return" of your main function to try to pass out a value. The return value from the main function of a program is a flag for the operating system that indicates how the program ran; 0 means the program ran fine, any other value indicates an error code. Instead you want to print the value out.